# Why does MYSQL Server "go away" under PHP 5.4.11, but not under 5.3.17?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, installation

I've migrated to PHP 5.4.11 which works except that it'll give "MySQL server has gone away" errors in long maintenance scripts. PHP 5.3.17 didn't do this.

Do I need to add/remove php.ini or my.cnf directives? Do I need to update my query PHP class script (we're using mysqli extension)?

Comment: I have it also in 5.3. It mostly depends on your connection expiring time: my.cnf

Comment: I *don't* have it in 5.3.X but have it in 5.4.X. I have servers on PHP 5.3.X connecting to the same MySQL server that the server on PHP 5.4.X is connecting to so I'd rather not fiddle with my.cnf.

Comment: i don't have a php.ini right now to check but maybe you should have a look whether there are any database related values in there, it just has to be that

Comment: Are you using `mysql_pconnect()` to connect to databases?

Comment: Have you checked max_connections setup in /etc/my.cnf? If it's a busy website, you need to increase that value. For example,  under the [mysqld] section add:
max_connections = 500

Answer (score 5):

You should check the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) under `C.5.2.9. MySQL server has gone away`. It lists many probable reasons why this could happen. Its mentioned on the page :

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is
>   that the server timed out and closed the connection.

Since you are running long maintenance scripts, I suspect that's the reason. Another point from the page:

> By default, the server closes the connection after eight hours if
>   nothing has happened. You can change the time limit by setting the
>   wait_timeout variable when you start mysqld. See Section 5.1.4,
>   “Server System Variables”.

You can try setting `mysqli.reconnect` to 1 (in your php.ini), or increasing `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` from [options](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php). See the [mysqli config](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php). You should also look into [migrating from 5.3 to 5.4](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.php) notes. It's hard to pinpoint the issue without looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

connect_timeout wasn't the issue, I had to modify my query class and add the following:

`mysqli_options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND,"SET SESSION wait_timeout=600;");`